# Integral of $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\cos \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)d\theta } $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am sorry if it does not fit here.  I found some of the integral for the complementary error function e.g.

[image]

So far I did not find any integral regarding,

$\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\cos \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)d\theta } $

Or,  $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\cos \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\sin \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)d\theta } $

1. Is it not possible to find the closed form of the integral of complimentary error function with trigonometric function inside.
2. Can anyone share me any integral of complimentary error function that has trigonometric function inside as argument?

Comment: Firstly, you're integrating over $(0,2\pi)$, so $a$ does not matter. Secondly, $\text{erf}(x)$ is odd, so this implies $\int_0^{2\pi} \text{erf}(\cos x) dx = 0$. Thirdly, $\int_0^{2\pi} \text{erf}(\cos x) \text{erf}(\sin x) dx$ vanishes due to same reason.

Comment: @pisco OK thank you

Comment: @pisco its $erfc$ not $erf$. I think its a little bit different.

Comment: @hasan What happend you lost interest in your proble,1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g(x)$ is periodic with a period $T$, then $$\int_{k}^{T+k} g(x) dx=\int_{0}^{T} g(x) dx ~~~~~(1)$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \text{Erfc}[\cos(a+t)] dt=\int_{a}^{2\pi+a} \text{Erfc}[\cos x] dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \text{Erfc}(\cos x) dx~~~~(2)$$
Next note the property that  $$\int_{0}^{2a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a}[ f(x)x+ f(2a-x)] dx~~~~(3).$$
As $\cos(2\pi-x)=\cos x,$ we get
$$I=2\int_{0}^{\pi} \text{Erf}(\cos x) dx~~~~(4)$$
Again using (3), we get
$$I=2[\int_{0}^{\pi/2}[\text{Erfc}(\cos x)+ \text{Erfc} (-\cos x)]dx=2\pi,~~~~(5)$$
as $\text{Erfc}(z)+\text{Erfc}(-z)=2$.

**Edit:** Now we take up the pther integral
$$J=\int_{0}^{2\pi} [\text{Erfc}(a+\sin x) ~\text{Erfc}(a+\cos x)] dx$$
Due to the property (1) again, we get $J$ independent of $a$
$$J=\int_{0}^{2\pi} [\text{Erfc}(\sin x) ~\text{Erfc}(\cos x)] dx$$
Using (3) again, we get
$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi} [[\text{Erfc}(\sin x) ~\text{Erfc}(\cos x)+[\text{Erfc}(-\sin x) ~\text{Erfc}(\cos x)] dx$$
Next, use $\text{Erf}(-z)=2-\text{Erf}(z)$,
to write from (4) and (5)
$$J=2\int_{0}^{\pi} \text{Erf}(\cos x) dx= I=2\pi$$

Comment: Can you please double check the property you used in equation 3. And can I follow the same policy for $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {erfc\left( {\cos \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)erfc\left( {\sin \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)d\theta } $. Thank you.

Comment: Zafar Can you you give me hint to integrate $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\cos \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\sin \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)d\theta } $ like your reduced form in solution from in equation (3)? It looks so classy approach but I dont know how to start as $sin(a+\theta)$ inside the integral. Thank you.

Comment: @hasan OK I will try this, in the meanwhile you may accept this solution with an upvote.. You may put even this second question  here in MSE.

Comment: @Zafar I have put the question in MSE. Can you please take a look? Thank you.

Comment: @Zafar it seems very beautiful approach. But Can you tell me why did you wrote $(a+sin(x))$ instead of $sin(x+a)$.

Comment: @zafar I found another person trying to do the same. So, I tried to use the Cauchy Contour integral by asking question in MSE. Can you please verify? Because I could not do it in your way (I tried). And thank you a lot for sharing your ideas. Thumbs up.