# $\int_0^{2\pi }\mathrm{erfc}\left( \cos ( {a + \theta } )\right)\mathrm{erfc}\left( {\sin ( {a + \theta } )} \right)d\theta$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have found a solution of the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \operatorname{erfc}[\cos(a+t)] dt=2\pi$

But I am trying to solve the following integral:

$\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\cos \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\sin \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)d\theta } $

Is there any hint that will help me to solve this type of problem. Thank you.

Comment: Care to share your solution for the first integral?  It might inform how the second is approached.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity the solution is given below by Zafar. Thank you. Do you think this problem can be solve [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781857/verification-of-an-cauchys-contour-integral-of-complementary-error-function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(x)$ is periodic with a period $T$, then $$\int_{k}^{T+k} g(x) dx=\int_{0}^{T} g(x) dx ~~~~~(1)$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \text{Erfc}\cos(a+x)~ \text{Erf}\sin(a+x)] dt=\int_{a}^{2\pi+a} \text{Erfc}\cos(t)~ \text{Erf} \sin(t)~dt.$$
From (1), we get
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \text{Erfc}\cos(t)~ \text{Erf} \sin(t)~dt~~~~~(2)$$
Next note the property that  $$\int_{0}^{2a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a}[ f(x)x+ f(2a-x)] dx~~~~(3).$$
As $\cos(2\pi-x)=\cos x, \sin(2\pi-x)=-\sin x$ from (3), we get
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} [[\text{Erfc}(\sin x) ~\text{Erfc}(\cos x)+[\text{Erfc}(-\sin x) ~\text{Erfc}(\cos x)] dx~~~~(4)$$
Next, use $\text{Erf}(-z)=2-\text{Erf}(z)$,
to get from (4)
$$I=2\int_{0}^{\pi} \text{Erf}(\cos x) dx= I=2\pi$$
Here we have used this integral independeny of $a$, from MSE:
[Integral of $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\operatorname{erfc}\left( {\cos \left( {a + \theta } \right)} \right)d\theta } $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778446/integral-of-int-limits-02-pi-operatornameerfc-left-cos-left-a/3778487#3778487)

Comment: @Zafar I tried to solve another problem [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781857/verification-of-an-cauchys-contour-integral-of-complementary-error-function) using Caucy formula. But that is wrong. Do you think it can be done using your approach?

Answer (score 3):

I'll present a strategy that would also work with your first integral; maybe it's what you did, or similar to same. With $z=e^{i\theta}$, the second problem becomes that of evaluating the anticlockwise contour integral$$\oint_{|z|=1}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{e^{ia}z+e^{-ia}z^\ast}{2}\right)\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{e^{ia}z-e^{-ia}z^\ast}{2i}\right)\frac{dz}{iz}.$$Using $\oint f(z)\frac{dz}{iz}=2\pi f(0)$, this is $2\pi\operatorname{erfc}^2(0)=2\pi$. [It works](https://repl.it/repls/FrugalIdleCygwin).

Comment: is there any sufficient or necessary condition or any structure of the function $f(z)$ ? Thank you.

Comment: I tried this using your approach but I think I am wrong. The link: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781857/verification-of-an-cauchys-contour-integral-of-complementary-error-function)